# How to set the maximum limit of days and hours in a week-view type calendar in android

Tags: android, calendar

```
public class CalendarActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements           WeekView.MonthChangeListener {

    WeekView mWeekView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar);
        mWeekView = (WeekView) findViewById(R.id.weekView);
        mWeekView.setMonthChangeListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public List<WeekViewEvent> onMonthChange(int newYear, int newMonth) {
        List<WeekViewEvent> events = new ArrayList<WeekViewEvent>();
        return events;
    }
    }

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/month"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:paddingTop="1dip"
android:background="@null">


<com.alamkanak.weekview.WeekView
android:id="@+id/weekView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:eventTextColor="@android:color/white"
app:textSize="8sp"
app:hourHeight="60dp"
app:headerColumnPadding="8dp"
app:headerColumnTextColor="#8f000000"
app:headerRowPadding="20dp"
app:columnGap="0dp"
app:noOfVisibleDays="6"
app:headerRowBackgroundColor="#ffefefef"
app:dayBackgroundColor="#05000000"
app:todayBackgroundColor="#05000000"
app:headerColumnBackground="#ffffffff"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am very new to android and java. I am using alamkanak library (https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View ) and I want that the user shouldn't be able to scroll beyond 15 days from the current date and he can see only hours between 5 am to 11 pm in a weekview in android calendar.How to make that possible ?

Comment: As this is your first question Check out [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to submit a better question next time. The first will guide you on how and what to ask and the second will guide you with creating some example so we can recreate it to help you.

Comment: Please add some code to also prove you actually tried something